# netty sslcontextbuilder server sslcontext exception upon receipt of ClientHello

Tags: java, netty, bouncycastle, fips

*Edited after narrowing down the issue*

I'm currently trying to use Bouncycastle's JSSE provider in FIPS mode (from bctls-fips 1.0.11) with netty's sslbuildercontext (4.1.58.Final) on Java 15.0.1 to create a server SSL context. When the server starts and binds to a port, upon receiving a ClientHello the following exception thrown:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsContext.getSecurityParameters()" because the return value of "org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.getContext()" is null
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:478)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
```

The code to create the server sslcontext is as follows:

```
  val sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forServer(keyMgrFact)
    .trustManager(trustMgrFact)
    .keyManager(keyMgrFact)
    .clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE)
    .build
```

where keyMgrFact and trustMgrFact utilize BCJSSE PXIK instances.

I'm wondering if I'm missing calling any additional methods on the sslcontextbuilder as the issue seem to be that netty hasn't setup the underlying TLS context using bouncycastle correctly.

Comment: Please add what versions of everything you are using (java, netty, bctls). The stack trace is not particularly useful since it's swallowed all the relevant stack from the BCJSSE code.

Comment: Sure I appreciate the help. After some further debugging, I've found that the exception is being thrown when the server context receives a ClientHello (I've updated the original post with the details you requested). Is there a way to get further debug messages out of BCJSSE code?

Comment: BCJSSE supports Java Logging API. Setting org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider..level = FINEST in your logging.properties (along with lowering the ConsoleHandler.level limit) might get you more output, although I would guess the failure is very early and not really to do with the TLS code per se.

Comment: Have you set ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX in your java.security file? Are you using the bc-fips provider (if not, you shouldn't be using bctls-fips, but rather bctls). I was able to get the example at https://www.baeldung.com/netty-http2 working with only the BCFIPS and BCJSSE provider registration and ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm setting; perhaps it would be a good place for you to start from?

Comment: Ah, I was using the bctls-fips jar (and did have the PKIX set in java.security). Is there a reason why the bctls-fips jar should not be used? Having switched to the bctls 1.68 jar, I'm now getting a NoSuchMethodError: 'byte[] org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.decodeStrict(java.lang.String)'
at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsUtils.<clinit>(TlsUtils.java:54)
with BCFIPS and BCJSSE registered. I noticed that decodeStrict wasn't in the javadoc for the bcfips provider. Am I still missing something or is this a case of mismatched JAR versions?

Comment: Yes, you seem to be confused between our FIPS jars and the regular BC ones. Unless you definitely know why you want it, you don't want the '-fips' ones. Just use bctls and bcprov (at the same version). The provider name for the regular provider is "BC", not "BCFIPS", and the class is 'BouncyCastleProvider'.

Comment: Ah, I do have a need for FIPS and need to ensure TLS connections come up with all the FIPS related restrictions which is why I initially brought in the bctls-fips jar. Given that, should I switch back to using the FIPS jars? Doing so would bring me back to the original issue I believe.